# How to get object via interpolation if the type of the object is a composite type in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning Angular for the first time. I'm trying to use `@input()` decorator with an object type, derived/imported from an interface. When the `@input()` variable is of string type, it works. But when `@Input()` is an object, then I am not to able make it work.

Course-Card component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from '../model/course';

@Component({
     selector: 'course-card',
     templateUrl: './course-card.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./course-card.component.css']
})
export class CourseCardComponent implements OnInit {
     @Input()
     title: Course;

     constructor() { }

     ngOnInit() {
     }
}
```

Course-Card component.html:

```
<div class="course-card">
    <div class="course-title">
         {{title.des}}// PROBLEM NOT GETTING THIS
    </div>
    <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo"
         src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/angular-core-in-depth-small.png">
    <div class="course-description">
    A detailed walk-through of the most important part of Angular - the Core and Common modules.
    </div>
</div>
```

I was supposed to use `{{title.description}}`, but I'm not getting any value.

course.ts:

```
export interface Course {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    iconUrl: string;
    longDescription: string;
    category: string;
    lessonsCount: number;
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the object to the component?

Comment: {{title.des}}, des not exists in the Course interface. Supposed to be {{title.description}} ??

Comment: i am just importing as likethis , import {course} from ' ../mode;/course' ;

Comment: but title is Course type object !!So it should have all the properties and member of Course. @Input title: Course   and importing  import {course} from ' ../mode;/course' ;

Comment: Like its been said, desc doesnt exist and we cant see how your input is being fed. Add the parent component to get better help.

Comment: import {Course} from '../model/course'; look here i am importng Course . At this stage i have Course.

Answer (score 1):

It should be description instead of des. `title.description`. 
You can read more about [Angular template interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-).

And, Interface describes a variable type i.e. what properties an object of that type should have. It doesn't set the value of a variable.

You can create a Course object in a component like this:

```
course: Course = {
    id: 1,
    description: 'my course description',
    iconUrl: '',
    longDescription: 'course description',
    category: 'angular',
    lessonsCount: 1
}
```

Then, in the html template of the component, you can pass your course object to it.

```
<course-card [course]="course">
```

Your Course-Card component input variable: title can be changed to course to make more sense:

```
 @Input()
 course: Course;
```

And your Course-Card html variable name title can be changed to course to make more sense:

```
<div class="course-title">
     {{course.description}} // It would work like this 
 </div>
 <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo"
      src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/angular-university/course-images/angular-core-in-depth-small.png">

 <div class="course-description">
     A detailed walk-through of the most important part of Angular - the Core and Common modules.
 </div>
```

You can check out this stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8p7q3e .

Comment: I have a model folder which is having course.ts. and it contains
export interface Course {
    id:number;
    description:string;
    iconUrl: string;
    longDescription: string;
    category:string;
    lessonsCount:number;
}

Comment: @pinku4132 I updated the stackblitz link which you can see the code. And, interface is just describing a variable **type** but it doesn't set the value of a variable.